# JQuery, how can i target a document element by both class and data-id

Tags: jquery, express, ejs

This is the jquery currently, I am trying to select the element which has class groupMessages and data-id equal to (this). Currently, it makes the item clicked disappear (this) but it doesn't toggle the item I want to display, (the one with class groupMessages and data-id(this))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.group').click(function(){

        $('[data-id=' + $(this).data('id') + ']').toggle();


    })
});
```

The EJS looks like this:

```
<% groups.forEach(function(group) { %>
                    <div data-id="<%= group._id %>" class="groupMessages">

                                <input data-id="<%= group._id %>" class="inputMessage" type="text"> </input>
                                <input data-id="<%= group._id %>" class="btn message" value="Send"/>
                                </br>
                                <%= group.message %>
                                </br>
                                <% }) %>
```

Comment: `$('.groupMessages[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '"]').toggle();`

Comment: Mohamed-Yousef that works fine for toggling the clicked element, but doesn't MrG want to untoggle another element? The question's wording is a bit unclear.

Comment: that did it perfectly! Thank you very much. It's always the syntax in things like this that gets me

Comment: However, it does not work on the second element for some reason, only for the first. It works for the second element if I have toggled the first one. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('id').toggle();
```

remove data-id and replace it with id for all elements.